# How to remote save in Eclipse PDT like Netbeans?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-pdt, remote-server

I have a problem with Eclipse remote save.

I have been using Netbeans for 2 years, my projects are stored in local and also in remote test servers.

When I opened, change and saved files in Netbeans, it also saves (overwrites) the files to remote location.

Configuration of Netbeans is described here : [Netbeans Remote Sync](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/remote_synchronization)

Another thing is checkouted code from SVN is in my local, and I only commit from local, never from remote, I mean I use remote server only for testing purposes.

I decided to switch Eclipse because of other reasons, but I cannot succeed to prepare a similar development environment.

I tried remote explorer,it's complicated and I cannot find a solution to my problem. There are some suggessions by using Ant, I think, this can be easy thing.Ant is much more for me.

I am open to any suggessions, to prepare a similar development environment I described above in Netbeans case.

Regards...

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1526282/620537

Comment: my answer could help you?

Answer (score 8):

The link to the NetBeans page only shows the settings for localhost connection.
The remote connection requires an ftp server on the remote machine.

**First I will show the Eclipse settings for localhost connection.**

File -- New -- PHP Project.

Project Name : **SwitchLoc**

Click

[image]

Folder -- Next

[image]

Settings as shown on image. Click **Browse**

[image]

**Create a new connection.**

Settings as shown on image. Click **Next**

[image]

Only to see what's going on : Click **Next or Finish**

[image]

Back to Connection select the **one just created**.

[image]

Select a folder under your www root.

[image]

**Create a new php file**
Right click on **Switch** new -- PHP File -- echo.php

[image]

Richt click on echo.php -- Properties -- Run/Debug Settings -- **New** -- PHP Web Page

Settings as shown on image. Click **Browse**

[image]

Uncheck **Auto Generate** and change the **URL**

[image]

Switch to Tab **Common**
Settings as shown on image. Click **OK**

[image]

Start **Debug**
select `switch-local`

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Next:** Create a remote connection to a `Remote Server` with FTP and remote debug.

**Follows in the sequel.**