# Eclipse Auto-Upload on Save, Without Aptana

Tags: eclipse, file, save

I'm using Eclipse to develop a website, and I don't want to run Apache, PHP, and MySQL on my local computer.  I already have a remote Linux server set up to do that.  What I want though, is every time I save a file, Eclipse should upload that file to the Linux server.  Dreamweaver does an absolutely perfect job at this task, but I prefer many other features in Eclipse.

I am well aware that there are many, many posts on Stack Overflow about this topic.  I have reviewed them, but none seem to quite meet my needs.  I'll go through all the possibilities I know about, and talk about why they're not quite right:

1. **Aptana** - I specifically excluded this in the question's title.  Yes, it does what I'm asking for, but if you install it as an Eclipse plugin, it totally takes over your Eclipse.  I only want this one feature, not the whole 800-pound gorilla that changes everything.
2. **Remote System Explorer** - I want the primary version to be on my hard drive, not the remote server.  This is because I want faster file open, and code completion.
3. **GIT or SVN** - When I see other people ask this question on Stack Overflow, someone usually answers "use Git or SVN."  Well, I'm already using Git.  When I want to sync the entire project, and not just iterate on one file, I will do it using Git.  But standalone Git is way too slow if all you want to do is see your changes working.  I also don't want to see hundreds of meaningless commits.  PTP, mentioned below, is a little better and a little faster, but not fast enough.
4. **PTP** - This is an Eclipse plugin that not too many people seem to know about.  It has the ability to sync a local folder and a remote folder using Git, and it can do it automatically every time you hit save.  This is absolutely awesome, but unfortunately a little slow.  When I hit save in Dreamweaver, the change is uploaded to the server in less than one second.  The PTP Git operation takes 10 seconds on a tiny project, and I bet that wait gets larger with a larger project.  I'm a huge believer in super-fast iteration, and all that PTP waiting will really slow me down.
5. **WebDAV and FTP support for Eclipse** - It seems like this is no longer actively developed.
6. **FileSync** - Pretty neat, but only supports local filesystem folders.

Are there any other options that I've overlooked?  Or are my requirements so specific that there's nothing that fits me right.  It seems like there would be other people who want exactly the same thing.

Comment: I ended up using Dreamweaver for syncing files and coding with Eclipse.  I had the exactly same problem but no solution to it.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion and it is not quick way to do this, but very customizable.
In eclipse you can set external tools.That means, you can set a php/java script file as external program and send some params that eclipse gives you(`${resource_loc} ${project_name} ${resource_path}`).
So with script file you can login to SSH or FTP or what ever you want and sync your file or project with remote system.
Just in External Tools Configuration window in eclipse you must set Location to /usr/bin/php 
and in Arguments, you can set script path with eclipse variables as script args.
At last you should assign some short key to external program IF Possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider set up Samba server on your Linux and work on you local computer but store project in remote directory served by Samba from Linux or use mentioned FileSync to sync local working directory with network directory (which for Windows look like local and thus FileSync should work).

Or Dropbox?

Edited:

You are constrained heavily I see. Maybe you have on remote host rsync? You could write small utility to manage if your local folder changed (for Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx) and then synchronize folders with rsync via ssh (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps). This would be completely independent from Eclipse.

Comment: Hmm, when I have full control over the Linux server, that's a good idea, but often I'm developing on Bluehost or something.

How would you configure Dropbox to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a try with CodeSync @github (I write it)

or this one
https://github.com/zhwj184/remotedeploy

Comment: There are a few repos named CodeSync on GitHub, which one are you suggesting?  And also for remotedeploy, is there documentation or descriptions in English?

Answer (score 0):

Now I am in 2021, and most of the above methods cannot work at all.
Finally, I find a small plugin in Eclipse that is very easy to upload the files (may be not auto-load, but is very easy).

1. Install the "Alibaba Cloud Toolkit" plugin in Eclipse Marketplace;
2. Using the right-click "deploy" item to deploy the selected files/directory to the remote directory.

There is also a problem. In my eclipse, the inside Terminal is blank (for all terminals including local terminal and SSH terminal), [the blank terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Vyz.png)

But the terminal in RSE is ok.
[The terminal in RSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txI00.png)

I also tried to uninstall Alibaba Cloud Toolkit, CDT, TM Terminal, etc.
But the inside terminal does not work anymore.
So I use the terminal in RSE now and put its view, as I just want to run my code on the remote server.